# How to use selenium python to find and return all attributes that contain "cookie"?

Tags: python

I'm trying to return all attributes that contain "cookie". The "cookie" can be anywhere within the first div and doesn't seem to follow any pattern. For example, it could look something like this or be in a completely different structure.

```
<div class="product">
    <div class="random"> 
        <a data="7cookiek">
    <a class="messy"> 
        <div id="9cookiep">
    </a>
</div>
```

Is there a simple way to reuturn the full atribute content of all the attributes that contain "cookie". For instance, the code above would return

```
7cookiek
9cookiep
```

Comment: Must you use selenium? BeautifulSoup would be easier

Comment: My first instinct was to use selenium due to the website not containing all the information until you scroll. Is there a way to handle infinite scrolling pages in BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Nope you can't. Yeah so selenium. Could you provide the link maybe for testing?

Comment: And to what extend can you scrape the data? Could you retrieve the lines with cookie already? Based on your example, the tags are different even among the cookies you are looking for. Why not you scrape all of them & then only process them after? Use something like `if "cookie" in attribs:` then `print(attribs)`